# What does (deleted) mean in the voting activity page?

Tags: support, profile-page, vote-to-close, recent-activity

I was taking a look at some of my recent voting activity to check on some developments on a post I voted on.  Doing so, I noticed that a couple of questions had a `(deleted)` indicator below the vote type.  It seems to appear only on question closure votes and nothing else.

[image]

At first I thought that I cast a vote to delete the question but the vote type would have shown as `deletion` instead.  Plus in most cases, I haven't even cast a delete vote on these questions.  Then I considered the vote got "deleted" when the question was eventually closed.  But that doesn't make sense, other votes don't appear that way.  Perhaps it is showing because *something* on the question was deleted (an answer, a comment, etc.) but this doesn't seem very consistent with other posts that have the indicator.

I'm not seeing this much on posts I voted to close on Stack Overflow but I'm seeing it more often on other sites where I have close voting powers.  I can't find a clear pattern to this indicator.  The closest thing I can think of that is close to a pattern are that many of them I flagged something on the post that was acted on but on the other hand, many of them I haven't flagged anything.

What does it mean?

Comment: Before you suggest that the post was deleted, this is not the case. Most of them (if not all) aren't even deleted (yet), [including the one shown in my screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314429).

Comment: Don't you think that the link should've been [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16314448/1190388)

Comment: @hjpotter92: you can't VTC an answer.